# Why can I cd into a folder I should not be able to access?

Tags: bash, permissions, zfs, freenas

I'm having an odd issue with my FreeNAS server related to permissions.  Let's just say I have a ZFS pool with the following datasets:

```
personal1  personal1:guest drwx------
personal2  personal2:family drwx------
something  public www:www drwxrwsr-x
restricted root:wheel d rw-r----
```

Let's also say I'm user `personal1`, who is a member of the group `guest`.

Naturally I should not be able to cd into `restricted`, or `personal2`.  But for some reason, while I get a permission denied trying to cd into `restricted`, I'm somehow able to `cd` into `personal2` despite the permissions denying this.

I can't `ls` the directory, but I can continue to `cd` into folders in this directory, despite not seeing this.  It's acting like I can execute the directories, but not read them, but the unix mode is very clearly `0700`.  ACLs seem correct too.  What could I be overlooking?

Here is some additional data:

```
freenas% whoami
personal1
freenas% stat personal2
14116848448016153017 34 drwx------ 34 personal2 family 18446744073709551615 53 "Sep 14 10:41:49 2020" "Sep 13 18:38:16 2020" "Sep 13 18:38:16 2020" "Aug 14 17:53:19 2020" 16384 65 0x800 personal2
freenas% cd personal2/
freenas% cd ..
freenas% groups
guest
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the output of i) `stat personal2` and ii) `groups` run as the user `personal1`.

Comment: @terdon I have edited accordingly